# How is HashSet<T>.Contains faster than List<T>.Contains?

Tags: .net, performance, list, contains, hashset

I have a simple requirement: I have millions of strings, and want to test if they exist in a small set. I'm in doubt between using a `List<T>` vs a `HashSet<T>` for this set.

When the requirement is the opposite, for example, you have 100 strings and need to check if they exist in a set of millions of strings, I fully understand that the `HashSet<T>` is the best choice.

But in my case, it seems that .NET has to calculate millions of hashes (calls to `GetHashCode`) when calling `Contains` on the `HashSet<T>`, so calling `Contains` of a `List<T>` could be faster?

Can anyone explain if this assumption is correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither of these seems appropriate to me - a `HashSet<string>` sounds like it may be the best approach to me.

Yes, .NET has to compute the hash code for each string - the question is whether or not that takes as long as checking for equality with each of the hundreds of strings in the candidate set.

As per all performance questions, you should really test this rather than guessing. For example, if all the strings have different lengths and they're all long, then `Equals` will be cheap against each candidate, and `GetHashCode` could take a long time. However, if all your strings are length 10 starting with the same 6 characters, say, then `GetHashCode` will be reasonably cheap but each string equality check will have to check all of those common prefix characters. Which of these is more like your actual situation? What have your benchmarks shown? How fast do you *need* this to be?

Comment: Very good answer! I found the HybridDictionary class, where you can store the values as null, making it essentialy the same as a HashSet i guess.

Comment: @Joshua: I wouldn't use the non-generic `HybridDictionary` class (which is for mapping keys to values, not just for containing elements) without some concrete performance data. Are both `List<string>` and `HashSet<string>` too slow for you? Note that `HybridDictionary` doesn't know where the switchover point will make sense - that depends on the actual data, and how expensive the Equals vs GetHashCode calls are.

Comment: I currently use HashSet<string>, but sometimes it contains 3 values, and sometimes it contains thousands of values, so i'm looking for something like a HybridHashset, which automaticly switches when item-count > 100 for example. I know it can never calculate '100' accurately, but it's estimation probably will be good enough.

Comment: @Joshua: Well you could create such a thing easily enough... but how long are these strings? Is this *actually* a performance bottleneck? What are your performance targets, and how does `HashSet<string>` work for you? (I can probably provide an example of where computing the hash is less expensive than checking for equality *even for 3 candidate values*.)

Comment: The strings are about 20 characters long, so maybe it's a case of pre-mature optimization, but I just wondered if there is a solution for cases like this.

Comment: @Joshua: I've asked a few times - have you checked the current performance? What do your benchmarks say? If you haven't *got* benchmarks yet, then it's *definitely* premature. Never optimize without evidence.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dictionary caches the hash of the keys, and clearly would calc only once the hash of the string you are searching. I will add that if your set of strings is static and rarely modified, you could find it faster to sort the immutable list and use Array.BinarySearch, but probably I wouldn't do it because it would make the code too much complex (unless by benchmarking it I verified that it was much faster.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The problem is that I'm searching millions of strings, so it can't cache anything.

Comment: So your problem is: is it faster to hash a string and search it in 100 other strings by hash or search directly by comparing it 100 times? You have to benchmark it then. I don't think the breaking point is fixed.

Comment: I think I found a solution: the HybridDictionary class, it switches automaticly at the breaking point.

Comment: Be aware that this class is pre generics. This clearly doesn't mean anything, but it's important to remember